# text/x-handlebars never showing up

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to develop my first application, and I can't get the browser to display my handlebars scripts

Here is my html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>Random Presents</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="lib/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="lib/handlebars.js"> </script>
        <script src="lib/ember.js"></script>
        <script src ="js/app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{firstName}}{{/view}}
</script>
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.AView}}{{surname}}{{/view}}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my app.js file :

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.AView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    firstName: 'Joe',
    surname: 'Bloggs'
});
```

When I load the file; the page is empty, even though the source corresponds to my html file.
I don't see any error in the chrome javascript console.

Is there something really obvious that I miss?
I tested the libraries, they directly come from the website and are on last version.

Worse, I actually even tried with a script containing only html and he won't load either.

Answer (score 3):

Because you created the properties in the `View` class, you should use the `view` property which is somewhat a pointer like the `this` keyword in some cases.

Change your template to:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#view App.AView}}
        {{view.firstName}}
        {{view.surname}}
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

Because of Ember conventions, both handlebars templates from your code represent the same thing. Ember assumes the template name to be "application" when there is no name. This means that even if you fix the property to be `{{view.propertyName}}` on both templates, the later one will override the first (or all predecessors with the same name), because Ember will compile the templates (with Handlebars) into template functions and the name will be used as a key to a collection of templates (path `Ember.TEMPLATES`), so that's why you'd have move those expressions to a single template like in the code above.

But you should avoid using views like this.

Views should display data, but shouldn't keep data. Your data should live in a model (in the store) and a view should ask the controller for data, and it should get it from the sore. The controller should be populated with data from the store through the router (it knows what to do and when to do it).

I'm not saying this in a bad way at all; just trying to save you from driving on the wrong side of the street since you're starting on Ember.

It's well known that there are a lot of outdated tutorials and this causes a lot of confusion sometimes (there's a [repo](https://github.com/trek/ember-outdated-articles) with outdated tutorials/articles which should be receiving notifications to update or add a disclaimar). But in general, I would suggest you to follow the [guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/), watch some [videos about Ember](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6yMxU-_ARs&list=PLLUBPLc28H8c8ihVHkYeRHe8OiB8P5WL0), check [other](http://emberwatch.com/) [resources](http://www.toranbillups.com/blog/) [available](https://www.google.ca/search?q=ember+js+tutorial) on the internet.

Here's a commented code of a very basic [sample application](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/mbuEL/) just to show some of the features you could and should be using:

**Handlebars**:

```
<!-- 
    when a template doesn't have a data-template-name, Ember assumes this is the 
    application main template. This is usually where you'd render the layout structure
    and also where you'd put the main outlet
-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h1>Example</h1>
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<!-- 
    As per convention, a named template should match with its route name
    There are ways around using "partial", "render", or even defining 
    a View class and setting the templateName property to a different name, or
    using the route's renderTemplate hook

    Another thing. You can have nested views when using nested routes
    This view template has another outlet to display a person from the collection
-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people">
    {{#each person in controller}}
        {{#linkTo people.person person}}
            {{person.fullName}}
        {{/linkTo}}<br />
    {{/each}}
    <hr />
    {{outlet}}
</script>

<!-- 
    Unlike the very first code piece in this answer, when you have a view or 
    template connected to a controller, you can access the data from the controller
    using handlebars expressions.
-->
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="people/person">
    First name: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="firstName"}}<br />
    Last name: {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="lastName"}}<br />
    Full Name: {{fullName}}    
</script>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

// defining routes which are somewhat like states (think of a state machine)
// they also provide the ability to have hash urls
// the router is a very important piece of ember due to conventions
App.Router.map(function() {
    // sample url ~/#/people
    this.resource('people', function() {
        // sample url ~/#/people/1
        this.route('person', { path: ':person_id' });
    });    
});

// In this route we provide the data to the list view in "people" template
// the data will actually go to the controller 'content' property which can 
// be a type of array for arraycontroller or a single object for object controller
// this should allow the view to call data from the controller 
App.PeopleRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.Person.find()
    }
});

// in this route we provide data for the "people/person" template
// In this case we are using the person id from the parameters to query our
// application store.
App.PeoplePersonRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return App.Person.find(params.person_id)
    }
});

// This is the very first route of the application
// Most of the time, you'll simply redirect from your index to a resource
// in this example, from ~/#/ to ~/#/people
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    redirect: function() {
        this.transitionTo('people');
    }
});

// The store manages your application data. Normally you only have to define
// the revision since it's not 1.0 yet (https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md)
// for this sample, I'm using the Fixture Adapter so I can add mock up data to the 
// app while testing/coding front end
App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 11,
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'
});

// Using Ember-Data, you can define a Model object which uses application
// semantics to describe your data, and does many operations which you'd 
// normally expect to see in a ORM. Ember-Data is no ORM, but it gets pretty close
// and in certain scenarios it goes beyond
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    fullName: function() {
        return '%@ %@'.fmt(
            this.get('firstName'),
            this.get('lastName')
        );
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});

// Using the FixtureAdapter you can add mockup data to your data store
App.Person.FIXTURES = [
    {id: 1, firstName: 'Joe', lastName: 'Bloggs'},
    {id: 2, firstName: 'Other', lastName: 'Dude'}
];

// when your controller wants to handle a collection, use ArrayController
App.PeopleController = Em.ArrayController.extend();
// when it handles a single object, use ObjectController
App.PeoplePersonController = Em.ObjectController.extend();
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll dive into that. I actually have an application with model and controller, but couldnt get any of my handlebar scripts to display anything so far, and this is why i stripped it that way.I ll definitely give it a new shot with your advice! thx again

Answer (score 2):

Within a template the default context is the controller, so you need to explicitly reference the view to access its properties: `{{view.property}}`

In your example:

```
{{#view App.AView}}{{view.surname}}{{/view}}
```

[Working example JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ixupad/165/edit)